# Find the max name

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max

[image]

I need to find the sum of the names and then choose the bigger.

I need to show that the max name is John smith because it's 4 times.

Comment: Sum of the names? Do you mean number of names?

Comment: You have two columns of names, so your question is quite unclear.

Comment: You probably mean to "count the names".

Comment: `select writer from t group by writer order by count(*) desc limit 1` will do.

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of the names"? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need the most repeated name. You may try below query -

```
SELECT writer, COUNT(*)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 GROUP BY writer
 ORDER BY COUNT(writer) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```